# Differences in variables constructed by counting.

Tags: repeated-measures, chi-squared-test, frequency

I have constructed a frequency variable from counting events of certain magnitude (e.g, 1,2,3...) from a time dependent experiment with animals.
I have two groups (Trained vs Control) and two phases of light (first 18 sec and second 18 seconds)

I want to compare Trained vs Control before and after the light change and I would also like to do it for every magnitude. I was thinking of splitting into four time intervals of 9 seconds and calculate the total number of events for each group to make it easier (and to have "comparable" numbers).

**What is the statistical test I should use?** Should I evaluate proportional changes, for example, TR group changed 40% and Crl group changed 10% or should I use some "expected frequency" given by the statistical test? **My hypothesis is that trained animals should change behavior (frequency of response) after the light shift.** I would also love to see a global change (for every magnitude of response)

I give you the data of number of events with magnitud 1 for each group as a function of time.

```
dput(t1)
structure(list(tiempo = c(282, 282.2, 282.4, 282.6, 282.8, 283, 
283.2, 283.4, 283.6, 283.8, 284, 284.2, 284.4, 284.6, 284.8, 
285, 285.2, 285.4, 285.6, 285.8, 286, 286.2, 286.4, 286.6, 286.8, 
287, 287.2, 287.4, 287.6, 287.8, 288, 288.2, 288.4, 288.6, 288.8, 
289, 289.2, 289.4, 289.6, 289.8, 290, 290.2, 290.4, 290.6, 290.8, 
291, 291.2, 291.4, 291.6, 291.8, 292, 292.2, 292.4, 292.6, 292.8, 
293, 293.2, 293.4, 293.6, 293.8, 294, 294.2, 294.4, 294.6, 294.8, 
295, 295.2, 295.4, 295.6, 295.8, 296, 296.2, 296.4, 296.6, 296.8, 
297, 297.2, 297.4, 297.6, 297.8, 298, 298.2, 298.4, 298.6, 298.8, 
299, 299.2, 299.4, 299.6, 299.8, 300, 300.2, 300.4, 300.6, 300.8, 
301, 301.2, 301.4, 301.6, 301.8, 302, 302.2, 302.4, 302.6, 302.8, 
303, 303.2, 303.4, 303.6, 303.8, 304, 304.2, 304.4, 304.6, 304.8, 
305, 305.2, 305.4, 305.6, 305.8, 306, 306.2, 306.4, 306.6, 306.8, 
307, 307.2, 307.4, 307.6, 307.8, 308, 308.2, 308.4, 308.6, 308.8, 
309, 309.2, 309.4, 309.6, 309.8, 310, 310.2, 310.4, 310.6, 310.8, 
311, 311.2, 311.4, 311.6, 311.8, 312, 312.2, 312.4, 312.6, 312.8, 
313, 313.2, 313.4, 313.6, 313.8, 314, 314.2, 314.4, 314.6, 314.8, 
315, 315.2, 315.4, 315.6, 315.8, 316, 316.2, 316.4, 316.6, 316.8, 
317, 317.2, 317.4, 317.6, 317.8, 318), cuenta.x = c(2, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 
2, 4, 0, 1, 3, 1, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 
0, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 3, 6, 2, 0, 4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 
1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 6, 3, 4, 4, 2, 7, 2, 3, 4, 2, 7, 3, 5, 5, 4, 
6, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3, 2, 8, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 4, 2, 6, 6, 7, 
3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 2, 5, 4, 5, 4), cuenta.y = c(5, 1, 2, 2, 4, 7, 
1, 0, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 0, 3, 6, 1, 5, 3, 1, 5, 1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 0, 2, 1, 6, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 6, 2, 4, 
3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 0, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 3, 
1, 5, 1, 3, 0, 3, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 7, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 
1, 2, 1, 0, 6, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 0, 2, 7, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 
1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3, 7, 1, 6, 
2, 3, 7, 4, 3, 4, 4, 8, 5, 4, 5, 2, 6, 3, 5, 3, 3, 7, 4, 3, 4, 
2, 5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1)), .Names = c("tiempo", "cuenta.x", "cuenta.y"
), row.names = c(NA, -181L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is a plot of data added into longer time intervals that show the tendency I'm looking for but I don't know how to test this statistically. Because I just counted the events there's no error associated directly to the variable, I think it's not necessary for chi-squared kind of test but maybe I should use another test. However, since I want to do the before and after comparisson within groups my guess is that it's not correct to use a chi-squared test.

[image]